# How to set the number of retry attempts of AWS Lambda in serverless.yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

In the AWS Console it is possible to configure the number of retry attempts the Lambda Function will make in case of failure:

[image]

Is there any parameter in serverless.yml that allows the user to set that configuration?

Comment: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/streams/#setting-the-maximumretryattempts ?

Comment: I'm actually using this: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3/ but let me try maybe it works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[2020-09 updated answer] As of [v1.78.0](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/releases/tag/v1.78.0), serverless now supports `maximumRetryAttempts` (and `maximumEventAge`).

[2020-01 original answer] At the time of posting, Serverless Framework does not yet support the configuration of Lambda retry counts. Note that the underlying feature [became available](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-max-retry-attempts-event-age-asynchronous-invocations/) from AWS Lambda on Nov 25, 2019. It is being tracked by Serverless as [issues/7012](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/7012).

Comment: As of release https://github.com/serverless/serverless/releases/tag/v1.78.0 serverless framework supports it.

See here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions#maximum-event-age-and-maximum-retry-attempts